# Could disable_irq defer an incoming interrupt or just skip it forever

Tags: embedded, microcontroller

I'm working with a STM32 system, and I need to receive bytes over UART RX, the thing is I have to synchronize the process, which means when it's doing something else we can't run the ISR, vice versa. Apparently the easiest way is to disable the irq during that "critical section". But I worry about the consequence of that, If I'm running in that critical section and a interrupt is about to arise but been disabled, could that interrupt comes out as soon as I enable the irq again, or should I lost that data brought by a interrupt?

Comment: Use a DMA and spool bytes when possible.

Comment: It depends on how long you have interrupts disabled in your critical section.  If the hardware completes reception of a 2nd byte, it's likely that your first byte is gone.  (There may be hardware buffering which keeps a few bytes, but obviously at some point they will be lost.)  So, keep the interrupts disabled for very small periods, or, as LPs says, use a different technique to copy data out of the hardware into RAM, such as DMA transfers.

Comment: Please see my comments under the "answer" field: there seems no way to accurately buffer the HW interrupt when it happens if disable_irq is used.

Answer (score 0):

A properly designed system should have the interrupts be sticky (in that once they hit the interrupt controller, they're registered until serviced).

In other words, if an interrupt occurs while you have interrupts disabled it should trigger the processor immediately after you re-enable interrupts.

Then the only question is how long can you hold off servicing an interrupt before data is lost.   That's a question for each peripheral.  Sometimes the designers put buffers/FIFOs in, other times you need to service it quick or risk losing the data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Russ.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Russ.  In fact I came up with an idea today, assuming the HW won't be able to store anything during disable_irq, we must always handle the HW ISR and temporarily store relevant data coming along with, and we process those data in safe context later, which is commonly called deferred rountine in some OSes. This mechanism obviously increased the complexity but avoids the risk of losing interrupt-related data.

Comment: Sorry, my previous post may not be accurate, basically the deferred ISR routine is employed mainly for reducing the process time of ISR but not the coincidence issue. The key issue here is even when it's time to call the deferred routine, the actual HW interrupt may still happen (assumption is it could happen any time), thus there's virtually no way to synchronize the procedure other than disabling the IRQ. But data coming with IRQ may be lost during disable_irq